# Replacing a string in Mainframe dataset

Tags: mainframe

Can we replace part of data with another string in Mainframe?
e.g. Suppose I have a PS of length 80.
From col 72 to 80 some line numbers are present.
I want to change these line numbers by particular string say TEST.
Can we use any form of "C ALL" to achieve this???
ABC File---

```
=COLS> -1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8
000004    text123                                                      12360002
000005    textabc                                                      12370002
```

Regards,
Saisha

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this in the ISPF editor (which is clear from your example) easily: `C p‘#’ ‘TEST’ 72-80` will replace any numeric string in columns 72 through 80 with "TEST".

Comment: Good answer... When in ISPF may also have to turn numbering off: Type "NUMBER OFF" on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two options:

a) Use DFSORT with INREC IF statements, or;

b) Use FILE-AID.

Here is an example with FILE-AID Batch processing:

```
//STEPNAME EXEC PGM=FILEAID,PARM=TSO
//DD01     DD DSN=INPUT.FILE,DISP=SHR
//DD01O    DD DSN=OUTPUT.FILE1,DISP=OLD
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSLIST  DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSTOTAL DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSIN    DD *
$$DD01 COPY  EDITALL=(72,6,C'AAAA',C'BBBBBBBB')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of options, none of which do an "in-place" change of the data.  That is, they will read the input and write a new file as output.

- Whichever SORT product you have ([DFSORT](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r12/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r12.ice/ice.htm), [SYNCSORT](http://www.syncsort.com/ProductsServices/MFX.aspx) (who inexplicably don't publish their manuals online), etc.) will likely be able to do this.  Accessing such utilities via a CALL is possible but they are normally executed as standalone steps within a jobstream.  Though these products don't come for free with z/OS, it would be exceedingly rare to find a mainframe shop without one.
- [awk](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r12/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r12.bpxa500/awk.htm), which is not likely to be CALLable in any easy fashion.  This comes for free with z/OS.
- [sed](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r12/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r12.bpxa500/sed.htm), which is not likely to be CALLable in any easy fashion.  This comes for free with z/OS.
- [File-Aid](http://www.compuware.com/mainframe-solutions/file-aid-data-management.html?gclid=CISnmabEz6wCFY3JKgodRSSzpQ), the CALLability of which I cannot speak for.  This is a third-party product and is not free.  You may or may not have it in your shop.
- Write your own.  If it needs to be CALLable then you can write it in your language of choice.  If it doesn't need to be CALLable then you have even more options, [Easytrieve](http://www.ca.com/us/products/detail/CA-Easytrieve.aspx), [SAS](http://www.sas.com/resources/), [SPSS](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/), (all of which are for-cost third-party products), and [Perl](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/z/os/zos/features/unix/ported/perl/index.html), Java, etc which are for-free downloads.  You could also write either standalone [Rexx](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r12/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r12.ikjc300/toc.htm) or use Rexx or [Clist](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r12/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r12.ikjb800/toc.htm) to create an [ISPF](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r12/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r12.isp/isp.htm) [edit macro](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r12/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r12.f54em00/toc.htm) that you could then execute in [batch](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21023990).

There are no doubt other options.

Answer (score 0):

I personally consider sequence numbers in source code to be useless and a nuisance. (It's also cols 73-80, not 72-80 btw).  Back when source code was kept on cards they were useful for resequencing a source "deck" which had been accidentally dropped with cards scattered everywhere.  Nowadays, with source stored on disk and edited online, they serve absolutely no purpose and nobody actaully uses them any more.  Whenever I find them I change them to spaces.  This also allows source to be stored in variable length format, saving considerable disk space ;-)  COBOL sequence numbers in Columns 1 through 7 likewise serve no purpose.  Changing these to spaces improves readability and makes any legitimate comments in these columns stand out better.